# Best practice in viewDidUnload?

Tags: ios, memory-management, viewdidunload

What is the best practice in viewDidUnload? To set to nil IBOutlets only or each instance variable too (release before)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release instance variables before setting to nil. You don't really need to set them to nil, though.

Basically, you do the tear down of any code in viewDidLoad.